# reading data from multiple excels and pick values and append into new excel using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, python-requests

I have multiple excel files. The dataset is in sheet 1 in all excels. I want to pick data from a specific row (6734) and column from all the excelss and append all picked values into new excel or csv file.

I have written the codes but not working

```
import os
import xlwt
import xlrd

index=0

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
Testsheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')
print ("Enter the row you want")
row=input(6374)
print ("Enter the column you want")
col=input(1)
path= 'E:/Vishal_Work/Rapti_Flood_Work/Rainfall_data/imdforecasteddata'

for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
    xlsfiles=[ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx') ]
for xlsfile in xlsfiles:
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(root,xlsfile))
    n = len(wb.sheets())

for s in range(n) :
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(s)
        data=sheet.cell(row,col).value
        print (data)
        Testsheet.write(index, 0, data)
        index=index+1

workbook.save('Test.xlsx')
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: code is not running and even not showing any error

Comment: Are the print statements working/

Comment: no it is not working and also not giving any error